# manage empty list php

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i am trying to manage a list with sortable ui jquery where i have two list in first list items are available in my website and in 2nd list the items are not available in website , basically i want a drag and drop ui so that i can drag the available items and unavailable items and update to database in available list and unavailable list respectively .

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Handle empty lists</title>
    <style>
     #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
    .chseq {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: 1px solid #C1C5C6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
       }
    .leg {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.chseq:active {
    background-color: #B9B9B9;
    border: 1px solid #C1C5C6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
}
  #sortable li {
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 18px;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
  </style>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float: left; margin-right: 10px; background: #eee; padding: 5px; width: 300px;}
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li, #sortable3 li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.2em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "ul"
    });

    $( "ul.dropfalse" ).sortable({
      connectWith: "ul",
      dropOnEmpty: false
    });

    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="display_cat.php" method="get" >
<fieldset class="leg"><legend>visible list</legend>
<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <?php 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `cate_avail` LIKE 'Y' ORDER BY `category`.`sequence` ASC ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
     while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {?>
  <li id="foo_" class="chseq"><?php echo $arr[1]; ?><input hidden type="hidden" name="unhide[]" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $arr[0]; ?>" checked ></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="leg"><legend>
Empty list</legend>
<ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">

<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `cate_avail` LIKE 'N' ORDER BY `category`.`sequence` ASC ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
     while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {?>
  <li  class="chseq"><?php echo $arr[1]; ?><input hidden type="hidden" name="hide[]" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $arr[0]; ?>" checked ></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul></fieldset>

 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

basically i want to submit the elements of both the fieldset with different name of array so that i can update the rows for available and unavailable products.

Comment: i am having two lists 1 has available category names and 2 has not-available category names .I want to reshuffle the list from the above code and submit so that it can be saved in my db .
currently i am having two different pages for hiding and unhinding the  category but after that i realize that i can make it in a single form by using jquery ui sortable plugin.

Comment: You are not showing any of the event handling javascript.  That is the most important piece.

Comment: i am not using any javascript i have to just save that content on my db .

Comment: So what is not working in the shared code..? please edit and update the question with proper info rather than adding comments...